# Spring MVC CRUD Operations using JDBCTemplateClass

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

How can I use use `Spring MVC` and `JdbcTemplate` class to perform CRUD operations on the `Employee` table?

Any suggestions?

Comment: there are a lot of tutorials about spring mvc + crud. What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Its bit difficult to explain all but I will try my best .

First create a model class say

```
    public class Employee {
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String email;
        private String address;
        private String telephone;

        public Employee() {
        }

public Employee(int id,String name, String email, String address, String telephone) {
    this.id=id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.address = address;
    this.telephone = telephone;
}


    // add getters and setters here
}
```

define a interface for Data access (DAO)

```
public interface EmployeeDAO {

    public void saveOrUpdate(Employee employee);

    public void delete(int Id);

    public Employee get(int Id);

    public List<Employee> list();
}
```

now implement DAO

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public EmployeeDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(Employee employee) {
        // implementation details goes here...
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        // implementation details goes here...
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> list() {
        // implementation details goes here...
    }

    @Override
    public Contact get(int Id) {
        // implementation details goes here...
    }

}
```

If i know exactly what you have tried and where you are struck I can help you !! Its difficult to explain how to go about it when I dont where exactly you are

Comment: Please mark the answer if you have found it useful

Comment: Hi Nishil saw your comment below and since I dont have enough repo to comment everywhere I am commenting here, your error seems like a tomcat server error, I think the config file is missing in your tomcat work directory

Answer (score 0):

If you need a skeleton to start with Spring MVC CRUD

[Spring Mvc Skeleton](https://github.com/Fruzenshtein/spr-mvc-hib.git)

Comment: Please mark the answer if you have found it useful

Comment: I have prepared all the required files : DAO, Controller,Configuration,view(Jsp)

Answer (score 0):

Please configure application context first.

Then you can use `JdbcTemplate`.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://${mysql.host}:${mysql.port}/${mysql.db}?characterEncoding=utf8&amp;autoReconnectForPools=true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${mysql.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${mysql.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I have configured the applicationContext.xml file :

Comment: <bean id="dataSource"      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeedb</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username"><value>admin123</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">        <value>admin123</value>
    </property></bean><bean id="jdbcTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /></bean>

Comment: I am getting an error when I run the application : The Tomcat server configuration at \Servers3\Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition (Runtime) v3.0 at localhost-config is missing. Check the server for errors.